# How to use Groovy CodeVisitorSupport visitor class when parsing a gradle script?

Tags: gradle, groovy

I would like to parse an android app's build.gradle file in Java and I am trying to use Groovy CodeVistorSupport for that as follows:

```
public class parseBuildGradle extends CodeVisitorSupport{
   @Override
    public void visitMethodCallExpression(MethodCallExpression call)
    {
        //My code
    }
}
```

In order to use this class, I assume I should somehow get the compilation unit or ast and then call the class. However, I am not sure what APIs I should be using and unfortunately I could not find any related documentation. I am wondering if anyone can help me with that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below is a possible answer to my question:

```
SourceUnit unit = SourceUnit.create("gradle", gradleFileToString);
unit.parse();
unit.completePhase();
unit.convert();
visitScriptCode(unit, new parseBuildGradle());

private void visitScriptCode(SourceUnit source, GroovyCodeVisitor transformer) {
   source.getAST().getStatementBlock().visit(transformer);
   for (Object method : source.getAST().getMethods()) {
       MethodNode methodNode = (MethodNode) method;
       methodNode.getCode().visit(transformer);
   }
}
```

Comment: You can accept your own answer!
Which library do I need to use in my project so that I can run this code? Maven coordinates?